# It's possible to use Google maps directions api with bus lanes?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, directions

I'm using the Google Maps Directions Api for javascript with Travel Mode Driving to draw a route, but i need to go through a bus lane and google doesn't allow me to do that.

I tried to change the driving model to Transit instead of Driving, but it's also not working.

Exists any option to indicate that the route is designed for a bus so the route could use the bus lanes?

The street name is Av. Marques de Campo in Gandia. I want to go to number 14 to number 8. 
[View route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxAXB.png)

Thanks.